# How to access json in php from output stream?

Tags: php, android, json, stream

In Android i have added key value pair in Output stream.

How can I access this key in PHP?

```
outputstream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);           //key
                    outputstream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"iddd\"" + lineEnd);
                    outputstream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                    outputstream.writeBytes("37");    //value
                    outputstream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i get your question.. it's a post request.

You can access it in your php script by using `POST`.

```
$_POST["your_key"];
```

Comment: Actually I was confused about whether its json or not then after crosscheck I got to know that its JSON. Thanks again! Have a good day!